# How to use mySQL with Apache Tomcat 6

Tags: mysql, tomcat

I was using MS-Access and Tomcat 6.0 previously for my application testing and it was working fine.

Now I want to use mySQL database through Apache Tomcat 6.0. I have WAMP server installed on my computer and I want to connect to the mySQL server. I have succesfully created a database on it. I have put mysql-connector-java-5.1.9, mysql-5.0.85-win32 , mySQL driver in lib of tomcat 6.0 as well as that of my application to ensure it is in classpath. I have following code in my jsp.

```
Driver d = (Driver)Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:3306///tmp/mysql.sock",
                        "admin", "admin");



[wampmysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I am getting error as

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:128)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.insert_jsp._jspService(insert_jsp.java:78)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:574)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What changes do I have to make in my web.xml file/server manager?

Comment: You have asked this same question four times, and gotten the same answer each time.  What else do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project","admin", "admin");

Note there was : missing before local host.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the mysql driver JAR file in apache-tomcat/common/lib/ directory

You can download it from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html

You need to put the mysql-connector.jar there

Comment: I have mysql-connector-java-5.1.9 , mysql-5.0.85-win32 , MS sql driver in both \Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\lib  and in webapps\application\WEB-INF\lib

Answer (score 1):

Did you download the MySQL JDBC driver from

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j.html
```

Is that jar file in your classpath?  The error you are showing indicates that the MySQL JDBC Driver IS NOT in your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

> I have put mysql-connector-java-5.1.9 , mysql-5.0.85-win32 , MS sql driver in lib of tomcat 6.0 as wel as that of my application to ensure it is in classpath.

First, what are the actual files?

- mysql-connector-java-5.1.9 - I'm assuming this is the JDBC driver - the actual file should be mysql-connector-java-5.1.9-bin.jar
- mysql-5.0.85-win32 - what is this?  The MySql installer? If so, you don't need this.
- MS sql driver - I thought you wanted MySQL?

Second - "in lib of tomcat 6.0 as wel as that of my application to ensure it is in classpath." - Don't do this... it needs to be in one or the other - *not both*.

Third - "`jdbc:mysql:3306///tmp/mysql.sock`" - isn't a correct JDBC connection URL - it's something like - `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/`*databaseName*

You should be able to copy mysql-connector-java-5.1.9-bin.jar into *either* your Tomcat lib directory or packaged in your WAR's lib directory, and then use the correct JDBC connection string to connect to this database in your code.

There's a page on how to set up many databases (including MySQL) as a [JNDI DataSource in Tomcat 6.0](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) - this is above and beyond what you're trying to do here, but the initial steps are the same, and it provides some example configurations.

Comment: I have tried keeping mysql-connector-java-5.1.9-bin.jar in tomcat\lib or application\web-inf\lib but now I am getting error as 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:3306//localhost:3306/project
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)

Comment: Look at the third point above - the :3306 is the port part of the URL - not part of the protocol.

Comment: I mean I am getting following error. 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/project
Is it a classpath problem??
I am using another jar file(Imageio) that is kept in tomcat\lib and it is working fine.I am using following code now.Do u find any error in it. Note: I am using mysql of wamp server.
Driver d = (Driver)Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/project","admin", "admin");